# How to make a word clickable to send you to a certain reference in the bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, hyperref

I am trying to make a word hyperlinked and clickable that if one click on it, can see a certain reference at bibliography. I guessed `\hyperlink` works but does not. This is a sample:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage{hyperref}
 \usepackage[hypcap]{caption}
 \usepackage{cleveref}
 \usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
 \addbibresource{bible}

 \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,filecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=blue}


 \begin{document}

 \section{Introduction}
 ... phenomenon; Gent and Lindley \hyperlink{\cite{gent1959internal}}{proposed} a more effective strategy...\par
 \noindent... phenomenon; Gent and Lindley proposed a more effective strategy...\cite{gent1959internal}

 \newpage
 \printbibliography

 \end{document}
```

This is also my `.bib` file:

```
@inproceedings{gent1959internal,
title={Internal rupture of bonded rubber cylinders in tension},
author={Gent, AN and Lindley, PB},
booktitle={Proceedings of the Royal Society of London A: Mathematical, Physical and Engineering Sciences},
volume={249},
number={1257},
pages={195--205},
year={1959},
organization={The Royal Society}
}
```

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider up-voting and accepting it. If you have any troubles with it, please let me know.

Comment: At that time I was not at the level to vote and accept it. Thank you though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`biblatex` automatically sets hyper-linking anchors for the bibliography which we can access with `cite.<refsection>@<entrykey>` for example with the following command

```
\newcommand{\citelink}[2]{\hyperlink{cite.\therefsection @#1}{#2}}
```

which you can use as `\citelink{<entrykey>}{<linked text>}`, e.g. `\citelink{sigfridsson}{proposed}`.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=nature]{biblatex}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcommand{\citelink}[2]{\hyperlink{cite.\therefsection @#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{sigfridsson} \citelink{sigfridsson}{proposed} a more effective strategy.\par
\citeauthor{sigfridsson} proposed a more effective strategy. \cite{sigfridsson}

\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Comment: After hours of searching, this answer saved me! Thanks so much!