# Hyperref link to bibliography entry?

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, citing, links

Is it possible to create a link to a particular bibliography item?

I'm hoping for something like:

```
This \hyperref[MyKey]{link} takes you to the same place as \cite{MyKey}.
```

A full (non-working) MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This \hyperref[MyKey]{link} takes you to the same place as \cite{MyKey} does.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{MyKey} Anne Author, Thoughts, 3001.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

A simple solution is to set a `\hypertarget` in the bibliography item. The syntax is quite simple: Create the target with

```
\hypertarget{MyTargetKey}{}
```

and create a link to the target with

```
\hyperlink{MyTargetKey}{link text}
```

Everything put together:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This \hyperlink{MyTargetKey}{link} takes you to the same 
place as \cite{MyKey} does.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}

\bibitem{MyKey} \hypertarget{MyTargetKey}{} Anne Author, Thoughts, 3001.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

If you work e.g. with BibLaTeX, this gets even more hackish, but still works. You can set the target in the author field.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @BOOK{MyKey,
        AUTHOR    = {Author, \hypertarget{MyKeyH}{Anne}},
        TITLE     = {Thoughts},
        YEAR      = {3001},
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=red]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
This \hyperlink{MyKeyH}{link} takes you to the same place as \cite{MyKey} does.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is not a particularly nice solution, but I am not aware of a direct, elegant way.

Comment: It could be my build process (`latexmake`) or style sheets but pdftex vomits if I place the `\hypertarget` on the author's last name (`Author` rather than `Anne` in your example). Otherwise this is solving my problem.

Comment: Note that with `biblatex` there is no need for the hack: [How to make a word clickable to send you to a certain reference in the bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282649/35864)

Answer (score 7):

I have `hyperref` and I use BibTeX with keys like:

```
@BOOK{MyKey,
     AUTHOR    = {theName, theFirstName},
     TITLE     = {Thoughts},
     YEAR      = {3001},
}
```

In my template at least, `\hyperlink{cite.MyKey}{link}` is enough to make a link work.

I might make a MWE later, but in the meantime maybe this can help someone.

Comment: I tried your idea inside a command I was defining: `\hyperlink{cite.#2}{\citeyear{#2}}` but the link took me to the first page rather than the bibliography entry. I really don't want to use `\hypertarget`, how can I fix this?

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

\usepackage{hyperref}

makes links work in the introductory [example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX#Introduction) like magic ("\cite{dirac}" becomes a link).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}
\begin{document}
Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and Dirac's
book \cite{dirac} are physics-related items. 
\clearpage
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

This all works with the default [sample.bib](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX#The_bibliography_file) file.