# back-hyperref the whole word

Tags: hyperref

I use the following codes

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
  \hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
% ------------------------------------------------------------
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{definitions}{Definitions}[section]
\newtheorem{notation}{Notation}[section]
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}[section]
\newtheorem{example}{Example}[section]
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
 \begin{corollary}\label{cor}(\cite[Corollary 3]{4})
    A unilateral weighted shift $T$ on ....
 \end{corollary}

By Corollary \ref{cor}, there exists a polynomial......

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{4}{W. Arendt, J.R. Goldstein, and J.A. Goldstein:} {Outgrowths
of Hardy's inequality,} Contemp. Math. 412 (2006), pp. 51-68.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

I get

[image]

> When I clic on the number 0.1, I go back to corollary 0.1. However, I hope that when I clic also on the word `Corollary` I go back to corollary 0.1. Like in the following paper:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `cleveref` package to

- automatically insert the word "Corollary"
- make the complete name click-able

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
 \begin{corollary}\label{cor}
    A unilateral weighted shift $T$ on ....
 \end{corollary}

By \cref{cor}, there exists a polynomial......

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. For references, how can I do? I try with `\cref[Corollary 3]{4}` but it is not correct. I hope to insert also `Corollary 3` like in the picture.

Comment: @Student If you have the source code of the referenced paper (can be downloaded e.g. from preprint platforms such as arxiv) you can use the same technique in combination with the `xr-hyper` package. Other solutions with bibliography tools such as biblatex are also possible.

Comment: I hope that you include my example in your answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please see the picture. Perhaps you don't understand me very well. I want to cite a reference like `\cite[Corollary 3]{4}`. I hope that when I clic  on the word Corollary 3, I go back to bibliography. However with my codes, I must only clic on the number `1` which is in red color. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: @Student In the text of your question, you ask how to add the link to `corollary 0.1` - this is what I answered. If you insist on doing your bibliography be hand, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285710/hyperref-link-to-bibliography-entry, otherwise a bibliography tool like biblatex could help