# back-hyperref the whole word in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref

Inspiring from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/470046/back-hyperref-the-whole-word), we have

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

 \begin{corollary}\label{cor}(\cite[Corollary 3]{4})
    A unilateral weighted shift $T$ on ....
 \end{corollary}

By \cref{cor}, there exists a polynomial......

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \bibitem{4}{W. Arendt, J.R. Goldstein, and J.A. Goldstein:} {Outgrowths
  of Hardy's inequality,} Contemp. Math. 412 (2006), pp. 51-68.

   \end{thebibliography}

   \end{document}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

> I hope that when I clic on the word Corollary 3, I go back to bibliography. However with my codes, I must only clic on the number 1 which is in red color. Like this picture

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282649/how-to-make-a-word-clickable-to-send-you-to-a-certain-reference-in-the-bibliogra and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285710/hyperref-link-to-bibliography-entry

Comment: Thank you for the links. However I don't understand what should I do because it is not my question. My goalis a s follows:  I hope that the word Corollary 3 will be colorated and when I clic on the word Corollary 3, I go back to bibliography.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/285744/36296), but we can exploit the fact that `hyperref` already sets an anchor for all citation entries.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{urlcolor=blue, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}[section]

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev,nameinlink]{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\hyperlinkcite}[2]{%
  \hyper@@link[cite]{}{cite.#1}{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{corollary}\label{cor}(\cite[\hyperlinkcite{arendt}{Corollary 3}]{arendt})
  A unilateral weighted shift $T$ on ....
\end{corollary}

By \cref{cor}, there exists a polynomial......

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \bibitem{arendt}{W. Arendt, J.R. Goldstein, and J.A. Goldstein:} {Outgrowths
  of Hardy's inequality,} Contemp. Math. 412 (2006), pp. 51-68.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image: both the label number and the postnote "Corollary 3" are linked and coloured in red in "[1, Corollary 3]"]

If one wanted to do this properly, one would probably have to redefine `\cite` to also link the postnote argument, but that could end up quite tricky.

Comment: How would modify that definition of `\hyperlinkcite` so as to create the postnote equivalent of `\textcite`?

Comment: @murray Sorry, I don't quite understand. Can you rephrase the question? `\hyperlinkcite{<entrykey>}{<arbitrary text>}` just prints `<arbitrary text>` as a hyperlink pointing to `<entrykey>` in the bibliography. That's why we had to use the slightly redundant `\cite[\hyperlinkcite{arendt}{Corollary 3}]{arendt}`. As I mentioned in the last paragraph, if one wanted `\cite` to add the link directly one would have to modify `\cite`, but I assume there are some subtle issues there w.r.t. postnotes of multiple citations and the definition of `\cite` can vary wildly with the used citation package.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for your answer. In view of your remark. I think we can proceed as follows: `\definecolor{citeblue}{HTML}{617BAC}
    \makeatletter
    \def\ccitecolor{red}
    \def\ccite{%
      \@ifnextchar[{\@@ccite}{\@ccite}%
    }
    \def\@@ccite[#1]#2{%
      \hyperlink{cite.#2}{\cite[#1]{#2}}%
    }
    \def\@ccite#1{%
      \hyperlink{cite.#1}{\cite{#1}}%
    }\makeatother`

Comment: @moewe   Because I want that the braces `[]` are always colored. Please correct me if I made wrong.

Comment: @Student On first glance that looks OK.

Comment: @moewe I hope that you add it in your answer. However, I hope that `Corollary3` will be in blue color however, the number `1` (i.e. the number of the reference) will be in red. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Student I'd rather not add it to my answer, but if you feel it is important you can write an answer of your own - after all you came up with it.

Comment: I'm facing difficulties to change colors.

Comment: @Student I guess it would make sense to ask a new question about that

Comment: @moewe: `\textcite` automatically includes the author name(s) along with the number of the bibliography's cited entry. How could one modify your `\hyperlinkcite` so that it would not only create the backlink from the bibliography item to the place(s) where it was cited, but do in the body of the text what `\textcite` does?

Comment: @murray At the moment `\hyperlinkcite` does not generate a citation (so the name was probably a bad choice). `\hyperlinkcite{<entry key>}{<text>}` only prints `<text>` and links it to `<entry key>` in the bibliography. Something similar could probably be done for `\textcite` (at the very least `\textcite` could simply be wrapper in `\hyperlinkcite`), but what excatly would be the best course of action depends on the implementation of `\textcite` (`natbib` or `biblatex` or ...?), so if you are interested in that I suggest you ask a new question.