# Latex clickable text to jump to reference

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, citing

I would like to have a clickable text that jumps to one of my references in my latex document. Is that possible?

For example, make the text "Edwin Hubble" clickable to the corresponding articles in the references of my latex document.

Comment: If and how that is possible depends primarily on your citation and bibliography setup. If you are using `biblatex` as the tag suggests, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/282649/35864 is the answer. For some BibTeX-based setups, you may want to look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470060/35864. If neither of those links helps, you need to tell us more about your setup - ideally by showing us a small example document.

Comment: Note that there are more elegant methods if the text you want to be clickable is not arbitrary, but data of your bibliography entry.

Comment: thank you it worked perfectly !