# Make custom text refer to item in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, hyperref, hyperlink

I'm trying to make some custom text refer to an item in the bibliography. There's an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282649/how-to-make-a-word-clickable-to-send-you-to-a-certain-reference-in-the-bibliogra?newreg=0c049e5bb1054d7591acf6c6ecc5bc9c), but it doesn't work for me so far. The problem is that somehow it keeps sending me to the top of the title page, instead of the right spot in the bibliography (normal citations work well).

As per the linked the answer, I've added `\newcommand{\citelink}[2]{\hyperlink{cite.\therefsection @#1}{#2}}` to the preamble (I've added this right before `\begindocument`, but putting it somewhere else doesn't seem to help either). My in-text citation is like this: `(Adapted from \citelink{kant_groundwork_1998}{G, IV, 397})`. I've added the entry to the bibliography using `\nocite`, but it doesn't work for cited entries either.

This is the entry in my bib-file:

```
@book{kant_groundwork_1998,
location = {Cambridge, U.K.; New York},
title = {Groundwork of the metaphysics of morals},
isbn = {978-0-521-62235-6 978-0-521-62695-8},
series = {Cambridge texts in the history of philosophy},
pagetotal = {76},
publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
author = {Kant, Immanuel},
translator = {Gregor, Mary J.},
date = {1998},
keywords = {Early works to 1800, Ethics}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt, usletter]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage[]{hyperref}
\usepackage{footnotebackref}


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{date}

\newcommand{\citelink}[2]{\hyperlink{cite.\therefsection @#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Here is a piece of text with the link \citelink{kant_groundwork_1998}{here}, which doesn't refer (properly). 

Here is a normal reference \parencite[]{kant_groundwork_1998} that does refer.

\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[UPDATE 1]

I'm working in Overleaf. I noticed that when I compile this MWE with LuaLaTeX, it does work (but not with the Overleaf options pdfLaTeX, LaTeX, or XeLaTeX).

I would ideally like to get this (or something similar) to work in pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX as well (because I'm currently using the `\changebar` package which is incompatible with LuaLaTeX). Not sure if this is possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! In order to help others understand your problem and test solutions, you should always post a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/48973)) instead of code snippets. It should start with `\documentclass`, end with `\end{document}`, show your problem and omit any code that isn't necessary for that. Your code is currently neither working (it doesn't compile or show your problem) nor minimal (there are unnecessary parts).

Comment: There is a small typo here. The linked answer has `\hyperlink{cite.\therefsection @#1}{#2}`, but the code here has `\hyperlink{cite.\refsection @#1}{#2}`. We need `\therefsection` here as that will expand to the the number of the current ref section. `\refsection` will attempt to start a new ref section - which is definitely not what we want.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That has been fixed now, which solved the second problem.

Comment: Does you edit mean that the code does not work for you when you change the compiler? I could not reproduce that. The fixed MWE works fine for me both locally (fully updated MikTeX) as well as on Overleaf (I tested their TeX Live 2022 and TeX Live 2021) with pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX and XeLaTeX. See https://www.overleaf.com/read/pmprvjckwtbx. Can you recompile from scratch, ensure you have a recent TeX Live selected on Overleaf and try again. If things still don't work, show us the `.log` file.

Comment: Any news here? At the moment, I'm not sure there is a question to answer any more. The fixed code that is in the answer now works just fine for me (locally and on Overleaf with all engines).